# Slow internet connection using Realtek RTL8191SU

Tags: drivers, wireless, realtek, mint

I am trying to figure out why my Realtek RTL8191SU is slow.

If I am connected using this WIFI USB stick the speed of the internet is **1-3Mbps** 
If I am connected using in-build WIFI device the **speed reaches 30Mbps**

The speed was measured using speedtest.net.

What I have tried

- disable IPv6
- change DNS
- disable power management

info

```
System:    Host: desktop Kernel: 4.4.0-72-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 5.4.0)
               Desktop: Cinnamon 3.2.7 (Gtk 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.2) Distro: Linux Mint 18.1 Serena
    Network:   Card-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
               driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: e000 bus-ID: 02:00.0
               IF: enp2s0 state: down mac: <filter>
               Card-2: Realtek RTL8191SU 802.11n WLAN Adapter driver: r8712u usb-ID: 001-006
               IF: wlx24050f9a4604 state: N/A mac: N/A
```

iwconfig

```
enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlx24050f9a4604  IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"MYWIFI"  Nickname:"rtl_wifi"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.472 GHz  Access Point: 08:BD:43:29:A9:10   
          Bit Rate:150 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0 
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:****-****-****-****-****-****-****-****   Security mode:open
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=100/100  Signal level=82/100  Noise level=0/100
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

Full wireless info available here https://pastebin.com/K4FtatFC
Any ideas why it is so slow?

Comment: Mint is based on Ubuntu, but is not an official flavour. Please ask on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) instead.